# Graph zabbix and time navigator have different time periods

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, zabbix, timezone

why the time zone is different between the server zabbix ubuntu and console of zabbix ?
 the server time zone is ok (utc) but not right in the console(browser)

l tried the command 
dpk-reconfigure tzdata it works for the server but still different in console

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Zabbix server, Zabbix frontend, and separate widgets in the frontend all use different time zones (if they are running in different time zones or users access them from different time zones). Please see [ZBX-4437](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-4437), [ZBX-5939](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-5939), and [ZBX-8857](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-8857) for a bit more information. You might also wish to vote on [ZBXNEXT-333](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-333) (time zone settings per host) and [ZBXNEXT-250](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-250) (time zone settings per user).

Answer (score 0):

- finally I find the answer , I did it and it works
- Editing PHP configuration for Zabbix frontend

  1. Apache configuration file for Zabbix frontend is located in /etc/apache2/conf.d/zabbix or /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/zabbix.conf. Some PHP settings are already configured.

php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value post_max_size 16M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data 
php_value date.timezone America/Montreal

2. and also the file 
   vi /etc/apache2/conf-available/zabbix.conf

   php_value max_execution_time 300
       php_value memory_limit 128M
       php_value post_max_size 16M
       php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
       php_value max_input_time 300
       php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
       php_value date.timezone America/Montreal

   3.and execute the command 
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart